# Vue CLI + Axios TypeError: XX is not a function

Tags: typescript, rest, vue.js, npm, axios

I'm new to Vue.js, and I'm trying to create a Vue CLI, with a HTTP client through Axios.

I found [this useful setup](https://enetoolveda.medium.com/how-to-use-axios-typescript-like-a-pro-7c882f71e34a), as the project I'm making is going to be rather large, and I want it to be reusable as a template. I updated it a bit to fit current versions, but (most likely) not in a way that would cause this error.

I made a service, extending from the API class in mention:

```
import { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { apiConfig } from './config/api.config';
import { Api } from './superclasses/api';

const api = '/portals';

export class PortalService extends Api {
  constructor(config: AxiosRequestConfig) {
    super(config);
  }

  public async getPortals(): Promise<AxiosResponse<Portal[]>> {
    return await this.get<Portal, AxiosResponse<Portal[]>>(api);

    // return this.success(portals);
  }
}

export const portalService = new PortalService(apiConfig);
```

**My problem is** when I use the portalService in a vue context. It does not recognize it as a class.

I have the following vue file, `PortalsList.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Portals</h2>
    <button @click="getPortals()">Get portals</button>
    <table v-if="portals" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Portal Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Domain</th>
          <th>File Domain</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in portals" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.domain }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.fileDomain }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Portal } from '@/interfaces/portal';
import { portalService } from '@/services/portalService';

@Component
export default class PortalsList extends Vue {
  private portals: Portal[] = [];

  public async getPortals() {

    const response = await portalService.getPortals();
    this.portals = response.data;
  }
}
</script>
```

When I press the "Get Portals"-button, I get the following error in the console:

[image: Console errors]

I know I have a lot to learn still, and that there are loads of information to find, but I simply couldn't find a proper solution for my problem, which has brought me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem. The method is not a member of the class, since it is never bound to this.
I fixed this in the most typescripty way I could find, using arrow functions. Simply binding in the constructor gave me another error, which I then found out I had to correct certain places in the Api class as well.

The resulting `portalService.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Portal } from '@/interfaces/portal';
import { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { apiConfig } from './config/api.config';
import { Api } from './superclasses/api';

const api = '/portals';

export class PortalService extends Api {
  constructor(config: AxiosRequestConfig) {
    super(config);
  }

  public getPortals = async (): Promise<Portal[]> => {
    const portals = await this.get<Portal, AxiosResponse<Portal[]>>(api);
    return this.success(portals);
  };
}

export const portalService = new PortalService(apiConfig);
```